# Matching results to a new result column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I did read through quite a few posts, but I couldn't fins exactly what I was looking for.  If this has been answered, I apologize for double posting.

I'm using SQL 2012 and pulling a pretty basic query.  The problem I'm having involves having to select from the same columns twice based on results from the query.

```
SELECT
emp_id[ID]
emp_fname[FirstName],
emp_lname[Lastname],
emp_supervisor[Supervisor]
FROM empmst
WHERE
emp_act_stat = 'A'
```

emp_supervisor only returns the ID of the supervisor.
I need to pull from the emp_fname and emp_name columns again only if there is a matching supervisor ID into a new result column [Supervisor Name]

My guess is it would need to be a subquery but I'm not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` will do:

```
SELECT
        e1.emp_id [ID]
        e1.emp_fname [FirstName],
        e1.emp_lname [Lastname],
        e1.emp_supervisor [IDSupervisor],
        e2.emp_fname [FirstName_Supervisor],
        e2.emp_lname [Lastname_Supervisor]
FROM empmst e1
LEFT JOIN empmst e2
    ON e1.emp_supervisor = e2.emp_id
WHERE
e1.emp_act_stat = 'A';
```